# The underlying provider failed on Open with winform

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

I created win-form application and accessing sql express database using entity framework, below is my connection string,

```
 <add name="CLDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Model1.csdl|res://*/Data.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Data.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\CLDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

above connection string working fine in my machine and able to communicate the database without any error but when i published win-form application with Click-once deployment and install the application in other machine get an error.

"The underlying provider failed on Open"

I tried this [solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2012/08/09/error-quot-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open-quot-in-entity-framework-application.aspx) and some of other stack-overflow answers but doesn't work in my problem

Comment: Is the database also deployed to the other machine?

Comment: Try to get a hold on the Inner exception(s) underlying this not very helpful message. They will tell you what really is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I created .mdf file and included in other machine too

Comment: I dig into deeper with inner exception and found "A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to sql server. the server was not found or was not accessible"

Comment: Another *very* helpful message :-) It usually means that you don't have the Net Framework 4.02 or higher installed on the target machine.

Comment: Yes you are right, target machine doesn't have .NET framework 4.02 but have install the .NET framework client profile.

Comment: The client profile should suffice. Just be sure to update it to the latest version.

Comment: I just install the .NET framework 4.02 in target machine but doesn't help :( , I guess some SQL server read permission issue occurred for the logged on user but don't know how to configure the permission without sql express IDE

Comment: Too bad. You will have to fall back on searching for this specific error message on this site. And change the subject of your question.

Comment: Take into account that |Data Directory| for a program that is installed in the Program Files folder will resolve to that same folder. That may be the cause of a security exception.

Comment: Try to access the localhost\SQLEXPRESS instance in the server. There is a high possibility that it is not installed there.

Comment: To use an MDF file you need to run SQLExpress first. That will make your first install click-many-times-as-admin. Consider SDF or another lightweight database.

Comment: In target [machine](http://i.imgur.com/GftwLRq.png) have sql server 2008 without management studio, i can't access localhost\SQLEXPRESS without management studio. i make sure database file in right place, have install the right framework, i give the everyone rights to Data folder still doesn't succeed.

Comment: How and where is the database file deployed?  That `|DataDirectory|` thing is tricky.

Comment: I re-installed sql express at target machine with administrator privileged and problem sorted out, but not sure which reason getting error whether sql may be corrupted or current user doesn't enough privileged to database. Thank you every one for valuable suggestion